# What does The location specified for 'Data Files Location' has insufficient free space. mean?

Tags: docker, oracle

I'm running a oracle DB oracle/database 18.4.0-xe in a docker container in a Ubuntu Linux subsystem on windows 10. I want to persist my datafiles locally so I don't lose my data when I stop the container. I use the docker command below.

```
docker run -d -it --rm --name oracleXe -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD="Password1_One" -v /home/user/opt/oracle:/opt/oracle/oradata oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

When I look at the docker logs I get the following error

```
[FATAL] [DBT-06604] The location specified for 'Data Files Location' has insufficient free space.
   CAUSE: Only (999MB) free space is available on the location (/opt/oracle/oradata/XE).
   ACTION: Choose a 'Data Files Location' that has enough space (minimum of (3,609MB)) or free up space on the specified location.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig': Permission denied
mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/dbs/spfileXE.ora': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/dbs/orapwXE': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora' to '/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move '/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/tnsnames.ora' to '/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/XE/oratab': No such file or directory
```

Where is the Data Files Location and where does the restriction of 999MB come from. How can I increase it ? If I leave out -v then the container spins up fine without persisting the data locally of course.

thanks

Comment: You map the volume to `/home/user/opt/oracle`, probably there is not much space. Change that to another drive.

Comment: CAUSE: Only (999MB) free space is available on the location (/opt/oracle/oradata/XE).
So not enough space under /opt/oracle/oradata/XE .. either get the required space (clean up / add more space) or map the oracle data space to somewhere else where disk space is available.

Comment: Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /
none           246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /dev
none           246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /run
none           246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /run/lock
none           246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /run/shm
none           246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /run/user
cgroup         246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /sys/fs/cgroup
C:\            246265820 223675764  22590056  91% /mnt/c

Comment: Looks like ample space available

Comment: You are using bind mount. Try to use named/anonymous volume.